# Flicker/slow css when loading contentn and css async

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, asynchronous

so I am loading a new page and a css file for this page via ajax.

After all the css files are added to the page, I set the opacity of the page to 1, but it shows up without the css applied and after a second or so the css is applied. This looks horrible, how can I avoid it?

I did not find a clean way to detect when css fully loaded.

Any idea why it shows up like this? I think the css might not be fully downloaded yet, but as I said, I do not know how to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is AFAIK no bullet-proof way of checking when a CSS file is loaded and styles have applied without using a "layout" element, then listen for it.

F.ex in your CSS file:

```
#layout{ height:1px }
```

Then in your javascript (I use jQuery here):

```
var $layout = $('<div>').attr('id', 'layout').appendTo('body');
var check = function() {
    return $layout.height() == 1;
}

if ( !check() ) {
    var tries = 0,
        interval = 10,
        timeout = 5000; // max ms to check for
    setTimeout(function timer() {
        if ( check() ) {
            console.log('CSS loaded');
            $layout.remove();
        } else if (tries*interval >= timeout) {
            console.log('timeout');
        } else {
            tries++;
            setTimeout(timer, interval);
        }
    }, interval);
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that I am loading css files for every page, so I would need to edit every css file, which is quite some work and also not so clean. Is there no other way?

Comment: Well, I implemented an automatic way to do this now. I guess that is the best possible solution. Fixes my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure how this would affect your implementation, but you could:

- Have some default CSS in the header of the loaded page, this would completely hide all content which has the 'flicker'.
- In your dynamically loaded CSS, 'undo' this style so that everything shows.

If your page needs to work without JS - you'll probably need to consider how that affects things.

Comment: This does not work, because I need to run js fns when the page is loaded and not before.

Comment: It should still work - once your page is loaded and your JS runs, it would load in all the extra CSS causing the site to show.

Comment: Not, it needs to run some js AFTER the css is done downloading.